# How to click on file-attachment icon using selenium (with java)?

Tags: java, selenium

I am creating automation that automatically sends messages through LinkedIn. The code is working fine, but as per our current requirement, I want to click on the attachment button so as to pass the attachment also with the text message. There are a few points that I have already tried:

1. Unable to fetch the element ID as its dynamic most of the time.
2. Don't want to use offsets (x,y) because once anyone changes the size of the window offsets changes.
3. Unable to use XPath.

Then I checked for another tool "UIVision" which makes a solution to capture that particular area (save it in a .png file) from the page where we want to click and during runtime it clicks there. So I tried searching image comparison API for java, tried with ASHOT and Sikulix too but none worked for me.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say your unable to use xpath will you please elaborate?

The button has an id - it's `attachment-trigger-ember1079`.

If you're concerned about the latter part being dynamic, the attachment button also has a good title.
You can try using xpath string:

```
//button[contains(@title,'Attach a file')]
```

For me, on my linked in, this returns a unique hit on the expected attachment object:
[image]

If these don't work, there's also the option of using javascript to action the upload.
For more information on handling the upload dialog (after your identify the object) have a look [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)

Comment: Hi rich, thanks a ton for your answer it helped a lot and finally i got that button clicked. Now i am facing issue that when i am trying "sendkeys" with this, its not picking up my file.I also want to share here that my machine is ubuntu.

Comment: Share your code and error/outcome?  - I won't get time to look at this till Monday but trusting you when you say it doesn't work an alternative the switch windows approach : driver.switchTo() .activeElement().sendKeys("/home/path to file/filename.txt");

Comment: Below is the code I am using:

WebElement weF=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Attach a file to your conversation with ']"));
weF.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Clicked dbox...");
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("C:\\Setup\\output.jpeg");
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Written");
Thread.sleep(2000);

I am printing "Written" on the console once it sends the keys, It's even printing on the console but still, it's not writing anything anywhere. A dialog box is popped up, and the rest page is loading in the background as usual.

Comment: Easiest options from here is to use the AutoIT solution to send the keys to the file upload box - from what i can see LinkedIn doesn't store the filepath in the DOM (so we can't set it) and is handling the uplaod via JS and web events. I've checked the JS and i can't see an easy way to capture the data to trigger the event. - Next alteranative is the API path - that's more complex than autoIT but would be quicker .  For that you'll need to harvest the webdriver cookies and feedthem into the post. The api path is then https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/voyagerMediaUploadMetadata?action=upload